# How do I create a good login page on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to have something like this one : http://nocopyrightsounds.co.uk/wp-login.php

Any plugins for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the "Erident Custom Login and Dashboard" plugin. Works great! Good luck @HarendraSingh and welcome to SO.

P.S. Don't be discouraged by "fly-by" anonymous downvotes. They happen all the time. You just need to have thick skin over here to ask questions. :) Best regards.